# Issue when running Ubuntu in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I installed VirtualBox on a Windows 10 PC. I installed Ubuntu v. 16.04 in it. But when I shutdown the virtual machine and restart it, it asks me to install it again. The installation itself is not saved to my virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your virtual machine is booting from the installation media.

In virtual box go to your virtual machine's configuration and ensure that you remove the live USB / disk image from the available devices section. However, a more suitable place for this question is [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com).